# Vue JS v-model value update not working for on-click events

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I have a application where I'm updating value of `input` element on button click.

I'm using Vue JS `v-model` for data binding.

HTML :

```
<div id="app">
<div>{{ response }}</div> <br>
 <input type="text" v-model="response.ruleName" value="" placeholder="" class="editing">
 <button @click="myalert">Click me</button>
</div>
```

JS :

```
var response = {
    ruleName: "ruleJohn",
}
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
        return {
            response
        }
  },
  methods: {
    myalert: function(e) {
      document.querySelector('.editing').value = e.target.innerText;
        },

  }
})
```

Here is working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/38Lj971g/

Now, When I try to edit input value with keyboard, response values does change.

When I try to click button, Though input value changes but response doesn't.

How to deal with `v-model` for such on-click data updates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't edit the input value directly, instead edit the v-model it gets its data from, like so:

```
<button @click="response.ruleName = 'Click me'">Click me</button>
```

or, if you wish to use the method:

```
myalert: function(e) {
  this.response.ruleName = e.target.innerText;
}
```